# Saving .txt files to cloud in Android & iOS Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cloud, google-cloud-storage, icloud

I am trying to upload a serialized class data that I saved as .txt file. It is a ghosting data of racing game. What is the best way to upload these data to iOS iCloud and Google Play Saved Games?
Or maybe you guys have abother suggestions?

I am currently trying to parse it as bytes array and save it in iCloud key-value storage. But I'm having problem to make it works. Is it better than uploading the data as .txt file?

I also have a plan to make it accessible to other player as well, so people can play against other player's ghost. Thanks

*I am using C#

Comment: I don't have enough experience with iOS cloud to answer this question, but I've seen a lot of developers being really unhappy with iOS cloud functionality, to the point where they dropped support of it.

Comment: Is that true? I chose iCloud because it looks reliable, made by big company like Apple. Do you know spesific problem that other developers complaining on?

Comment: This question is too broad at the moment - you should make it about *either* iCloud *or* Google Play services, IMO.

Comment: Sorry if the question is too broad, I was trying to find a direction on how to do it properly and effective. I found out that any data saved in the iCloud or Google Saved Games is private and cannot be accessible by other players. So the possible way to do that is hosting the file on our own server.